# Cannot run Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu run via Termux

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, termux

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 via Termux proot.

I am able to login via VNC Server and use the desktop on my Android Phone.

I downloaded arm64 deb and tar.gz files. However, when I run VS code installed via deb or extracted from the tar.gz, I get no response. I get no errors either. Anyone know why?

Comment: To make sure I understand you correctly: you're trying to run VS Code on an Android phone using Termux running Ubuntu? If that is correct, please note that this question will be off topic on this site, as questions about Android and mobile phones/tablets in general are off topic here.

Comment: Is this on topic somewhere else. I found a solution. Use --no-sandbox and it runs.

Comment: On Android SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling sandbox works. Run code from terminal with the --no-sandbox option.